# Why does template argument deduction/substitution fail here?

Tags: c++, templates, memoization

I am trying to write a simple template that I can use for memoization with functions taking a single argument:

```
#include <map>          

template <typename F,typename OUT,typename IN> 
OUT memoization(IN in){
    static std::map<IN,OUT> memo;
    static typename std::map<IN,OUT>::iterator found = memo.find(in);
    if (found != memo.end()) { return found->second; }  
    OUT res = F(in);
    memo(in) = res;
    return res;
}

double test(double x) { return x*x; }

int main(){
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        memoization<test,double,double>(i*0.5);
    }
}
```

But i get the error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'memoization(double)'
>
> note: candidate is:
>
> note: template OUT memoization(IN)
>
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

**Why does this fail to compile?**

Actually I dont understand why template argument deduction/substitution is taking place at all when I specify all the template parameters.

I am using gcc version 4.7.2 (no C++11 enabled)

PS: the template has many more errors than I first realized, but I leave it as is...

Comment: `test` is not a type. `decltype(test)` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function template takes three *type* arguments:

```
template <typename F,typename OUT,typename IN> 
OUT memoization(IN in) { ... }
```

You're passing in `test` for `F`. `test` isn't a type, it's a value. Also, the expression `F(in)` in your function template is wrong for the same reason.

---

This approach in general is pretty flawed as it seems pretty backwards from what actually is going on. Namely, it's the function that's being memoized, not a value. Also requiring the function value at compile time is pretty limiting.

A better approach is to treat memoization as a decorator. That is:

```
template <class F>
Memoized<F> memoize(F f) {
    return {f};
}
```

such that:

```
auto memo_test = memoize(test);
memo_test(0); // performs computation
memo_test(0); // doesn't perform computation
memo_test(0); // ditto
```

I leave the implementation of `Memoized<T>` as an exercise.

Comment: ups. yeah stupid mistake. However, then i am not sure if it will still work as I wanted. The idea was that for each function I get a different instantiation of the template and hence an individual map

Comment: with your proposed solution isnt it the same template instantiation for my `test` and some `double foo(double)` ? In this case my tempalte approach would be rather useless

Comment: @tobi303 The whole approach is fundamentally flawed, updated the answer to give you a better direction.

Comment: Unfortunately he doesn't have c++11 available. Perhaps a candidate for using boost::result_of<> ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does template argument deduction/substitution fail here?

<strike>a. Because there are 3 template arguments and only one actual argument, so two of them are undeduce-able (is that a word?).</strike>

b. There is a syntax error. Template argument F is a type, not a callable object.

If this has to work in a pre-c++11 environment, `boost`'s `result_of` can help:

```
#include <map>         
#include <boost/utility/result_of.hpp>

//
// now that template arguments are all used when collecting function
// arguments, the types F and IN can be deduced.
//    
template <typename F,typename IN> 
typename boost::result_of<F(IN)>::type memoization(F f, IN in)
{
  typedef typename boost::result_of<F(IN)>::type OUT;
    static std::map<IN,OUT> memo;
    static typename std::map<IN,OUT>::iterator found = memo.find(in);
    if (found != memo.end()) { return found->second; }  
    OUT res = f(in);
    memo[in] = res;
    return res;
}

double test(double x) { return x*x; }

int main(){
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        memoization(test, i*0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: a. is not a problem, OP is explicitly providing all the template parameters.

Comment: @Barry so he is. yuk :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer already got a satisfactory answers, however I was curious if I could get it working with pre C++11. Actually it is possible to pass a function pointer as template parameter, one just has to specify this on the template parameter instead of letting it expect a type parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
 
template <class T, class R, R (*Func)(T)>
R memoized(T in) {
    static std::map<T,R> memo;
    typename std::map<T,R>::iterator found = memo.find(in);
    if (found != memo.end()) { return found->second; }  
    std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
    R res = Func(in);
    memo[in] = res;
    return res;
}
 
double test(double x){return x*x;}
double test2(double x){return x;}
 
int main() {
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test2>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test2>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoized<double,double,test2>(1) << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
not found
1
1
1

not found
1
1
1
```

Still not sure if this is a good approach, but it seems to work.